# How to fix "W: Duplicate sources.list entry"?

Tags: apt, configuration, software-sources

I keep getting this warning whenever I try to run `sudo apt-get update`.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Below is the output from `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 233):

***Your sources.list really has duplicate entries.***

First Let's see the correct form of a repository line or source line:

The correct format of repository source line is

```
<type of repository>  <location>  <dist-name> <components>
```

For example, a repo line can be like this one

```
  deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

<sup>Here, it means, the repository is for binary packages, which are hosted in http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and this repository is for Ubuntu precise (12.04) and this repository contains the main (software which are officially supported by Canonical) component.</sup>

- **Type:** The type can be `deb` and `deb-src`. `deb` means a binary repository where `deb-src` means a source repository
- **Location:** `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` location of the repository.
- **Dist-name:** The distribution name of Ubuntu release. For Ubuntu 12.04 it is `precise`, for 11.10 it is `oneiric`.
  <sup>You can visit the Ubuntu Wiki to view an updated [list of Ubuntu releases and their code names](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).</sup>
- **Component:** It can be `main`, `universe`, `multiverse` and `restricted`. These words indicates the level of supports for the packages and the licensing status.

See [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu/) for more information.

***Please take note that, you can add one or more component in a line, so "main", "universe", "restricted" and "multiverse" can be in a single line.*** Also note, Though you add more than one component in a single line, APT system considers them as separate line containing only one component.

So, If your `sources.list` have a line like this

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
```

Then it can't have another line like the below (which your files have)

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
```

which is equivalent of these two lines

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
```

Because, you are duplicating ***universe*** twice, so there will be an error for that duplicate. An error will be given for each duplicate found.

### Solution:

After analyzing your `sources.list` file, I found that, It is a basic one which is supplied by Ubuntu by default. You can build a default file following the procedure:

1. Open a terminal and first rename the existing `sources.list` file to `sources.list.bak` file. (we can safely remove that, but caution is good).

   ```
    sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
   ```
2. Then open `software-properties-gtk` to build a new one. Type the below command in a terminal or in dash command prompt with pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

   ```
   software-properties-gtk
   ```

   <sup>Note, for Ubuntu version 11.10 or earlier you have to use `gksu` before the `software-properties-gtk` command</sup>
3. After the window is open,

   - Select all four categories in **Ubuntu Software** tab
   - Select  *precise-security*, *precise-updates* and *precise-backports* category in **Updates** tab.
   - Select *Canonical partner* and *Independent* category from **Other software** tab.

That's it. You have now a default `sources.list` file without error. Compare this file with the previous one, if you want.

---

#### Update to deal with `sources.list.d` dir's files

Sometimes a duplicate entry can be in a file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, which is also used by APT. So, you should look at that directory and see if there is any duplicate in those files. It is not necessary for duplicates being in the same file.

#### Example case:

A user had this error message showing while doing `sudo apt-get update`.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

But there was no entry with `http://dl.google.com` in the main `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. Looking at the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory we found these files:

output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
aims-sagemath-precise.list
aims-sagemath-precise.list.save
dropbox.list
dropbox.list.save
fossfreedom-packagefixes-precise.list
fossfreedom-packagefixes-precise.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
google.list
google.list.save
sagemath-monolithic-precise.list
sagemath-monolithic-precise.list.save
```

The files `google-chrome.list` and `google.list` were good candidates for containing duplicates. So, checking the contents of both files was necessary.

Output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`:

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

and of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list`

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

So, there was a duplicate entries in the sources of Apt. Since `google-chrome.list` only contain a single apt line and it was also listed in `google.list` file we can safely remove this file with the command

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Then the problem was solved.

Comment: What did I do to cause myself to have duplicate entries in my sources.list.d?

Comment: @Seanny123 That is difficult to say.

Comment: link to [Solve Duplicate source.list entry](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/w-duplicate-sources-list-entry-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/) mentioned [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/414358/307410) solved my confusion. Try, and if it helps you, praise O.A.K.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering hours how duplicates occurred. Finally you showed sources.list.d

Comment: @IsuraManchanayake Glad to know that it helped you! It took me times from me too :)

Comment: Nice and thorough answer. In your **Update to deal with sources.list.d dir's files** you explain which are the files/lines giving the duplicates. Could you similarly explain which are the 6 pairs of lines (since you say "your file has 6 duplicates there") in the OP that give duplicates?

Comment: @sancho.s Strangely, I don't find duplicates at least from his pasted configuration here! Don't know why I wrote that line! May be it was a result of chat discussion or something. But anyway, that line is wrong. Sometimes this error can also be raised for malformed package list file in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. Thanks for being curious !

Comment: The hint to go check my sources.list.d was what helped me resolve this.

Answer (score 82):

**For Ubuntu 12.04**

Graphically:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `software-properties-gtk` (or you can open "Software Center" then go to "Edit" > "Software Sources"). Go to tab "Other Software", choose the duplicate entry and press the "Remove" button.

[image]

---

If you need a command line option, here it is:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | perl -ne '$H{$_}++ or print' > /tmp/sources.list && sudo mv /tmp/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The command does this:

`cat` reads the file and passes the content to `perl` which removes the duplicate lines. The result is then saved `>` in a temporary file which is then moved to replace the original `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: Just how to fix it, without confusion and all the too deep details. Thank you!

Comment: It actually worked! Could not, for some reason, install git on a 12.04 either. Instead of remove, I just checked the apparent duplicated "Canonical partners".

Comment: I ran the one-liner, but `sudo apt-get update` still complains about duplicate entries as if nothing changed. If it matters, I'm on 12.04 (specifically, elementary OS Luna).

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and prevents you from using `sudo perl -i`

Answer (score 24):

### How bad are duplicate entries in sources.list?

I don’t know how bad it is, but i don’t like **sudo apt-get update** showing me duplicate entries.

By the way its not that bad, its just showing you that you have duplicate entries.

### SourcesList

The sources.list file is a key factor in adding or upgrading applications to your Ubuntu installation. This is also used by your system for system updates. The file is basically the roadmap for your system to know where it may download programs for installation or upgrade.

Its just like Windows update

> You can remove duplicate entries in few easy steps with **Y PPA Manager**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager -y
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager -y
```

Open **y-ppa-manager** form **Dash**

> Enter You Admin Password

[image]

> Double Click On Advanced

[image]

> Scan & Remove Duplicate PPA's & Click Ok

[image]

> It will take some time ( 1 or 2 Mints ) To Scan & Remove Duplicate PPA's

Comment: In my case, Y PPA kept saying no duplicates found. I made a backup of the source.list removed it, and ran sudo apt-get update to recreate the source list (ubuntu 12.04). This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me on ubuntu 14.04..Thanks buddy..:)

Comment: worked like a charm

Comment: In my case on 14.04 it keeps saying  **No Duplicates Found**

Answer (score 16):

The partner repository is duplicated inside `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.list`.

Just remove those "precise-partner" files as the partner repository is already present in `sources.list`.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.*
```

Comment: I'm getting `rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.*': No such file or directory`

Comment: Try `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*partner*`. Also check your /etc/apt/sources.list, look for duplicate lines.

Comment: No luck, I don't have any files with "partner" in the name in that directory. And `/etc/apt/sources.list` doesn't contain any duplicates according to `uniq`.

Answer (score 10):

Make a back up copy of your sources.list:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.backup}
```

Now remove the original and update:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: How can he update without `sources.list` file?

Comment: It will repopulate. =)

Comment: mine did not repopulate

Comment: Revert to the one you backed up

Comment: How do I revert to the backed up list? the removal removed a lot of important thing... this is totally not safe..

Comment: @alvas same way you backed it up (I assume you back up a file by copying it somewhere. Copy it back)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, open software sources. unchecked "Canonical Partners". The Conflict is between "Canonical Partners" and " Canonical partners Added by software Center"

Answer (score 7):

If you couldn't figure it out in your `source.list`, then do this:

1. Left-click on settings icon (at the extreme top corner of your screen) and select System Settings.
2. Click on Software Sources and move to Other Software.
3. Uncheck one of the 'Canonical Partners(Source Code) -software packaged by Canonical for their partners' files and one of the 'Canonical Partners -software packaged by Canonical for their partners' files also and click Close to leave.
4. Simultaneously press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keys to open terminal and type `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but still I am getting this error.

Comment: Please, post the image of your 'Software Sources' here to know the culprit.

Comment: Please, post the image of your 'Other Software' here.

Answer (score 6):

#### 10.10 and Earlier

**Applications > Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Other Software**

OR

**System > Administration > Synaptic Packet Manager > Settings > Repositories**

[image: Software Sources config window]

Select and Remove duplicate entries.

Answer (score 5):

**For Ubuntu 9.10 - 12.04**

There is an app called Y-PPA-Manager which can do that and much more.

You can install it like that from a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

After that, just start the application an go to the Advanced menu.

[image]

Then select "Scan and remove duplicate PPAs" and hit OK.

[image]

Comment: It's cool tool but it doesn't fix problem. I did this choice and after this have the same warnings.

Answer (score 4):

I searched for such a tool, but I didn't find any...
So, I ended up coding one myself with `PHP`.

Sorry for the dirty unorganized source code.

### chkdup - Screenshot:

[image]

### Author

Mubarak Alrashidi (DeaDSouL)

### Requirements:

1. PHP.
2. sudo.

### Installation:

1. Open the terminal.
2. To install PHP if you don't have it, type: `sudo apt-get install php5 php5-cli`.
3. Download the [chkdup](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1526267/maScripts/chkdup-0.01-beta.tar.gz).
4. Extract the file anywhere you like.
5. Type: `sudo sh install.sh`.

### Uninstall:

1. Open the terminal.
2. Go to the path you extracted the tool in.
3. Type: `sudo sh uninstall.sh`.

### How to use it:

Just open the terminal and type `sudo chkdup`.

### FAQs:

**What does the install.sh do ?**

- The installer will move the `chkdup.php` to `/opt/` then will create a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/`.

**What about the uninstall.sh ?**

- The uninstaller will remove the following files:

  1. `install.sh`
  2. `/opt/chkdup.php`
  3. `/usr/bin/chkdup`
  4. itself `uninstall.sh`

**Is it safe to use chkdup ?**

- Yes it is, since it takes a backup of the current sources.list before attempting to do anything. But I'm not responsible if anything happened. The full responsibility will be yours.

### License

GNU General Public License

Comment: just tried it out, nice and simple :-) nice :-)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have two identical lines in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Go to terminal, and enter `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, then look for any identical lines in that file, and if you find them, delete them.  After your done, save and exit, and then do `sudo apt-get update` and that should resolve your problem.

If that doesn't solve your problem then you're going to have to use a trial and error approach.  First, create a backup of your `sources.list` file, then in the actual file go through and comment out or delete each line, saving and `apt-get update`-ing after each line has been commented out or deleted.  Going through this file line by line commenting out different lines will eventually tell you which line is the superfluous one. Don't forget to uncomment any lines you commented if `apt-get update` still shows the same prompt, otherwise you'll be left with no sources in your `sources.list` file.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`? Maybe you have some "extra" repositories in there?

Answer (score 2):

Install ubuntu-tweak and remove the duplicate entries from there.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

[image]

Comment: This does not say how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I try to complete the possibilities offered from other users using terminal, since that's what you asked, mainly:

log in if you're using a text based install or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type gnome-terminal if you're using GUI

Then type

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(To understand better: in the directory `/etc` you can find (nearly) all configuration files of your computer and in the `apt` directory you find the `souces.list` file that contains all the repositories that APT uses to update or install and upgrade software)

Edit the file removing or commenting with `#` at the start of the line any duplicated rows.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit and press <kbd>y</kbd> to save the file (or <kbd>n</kbd> to quit without saving).

Then update to see if you've fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Have fun!

Comment: I also think that evolved text editor like vim can automatically find duplicates but I don't know how to do that any kind of info would be interesting

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a single command line to find and delete duplicated entries in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

This is because the suggested command lines, which merely duplicate the function of the much simpler built-in `uniq` command, will only work on a SORTED file and will only remove ADJACENT lines. 
Furthermore, those commands will only remove lines consisting of an *identical string of characters*.

Duplicate entries reported by `apt-get update` will consist of duplicate *function* entries, such as a repository being included in both its `i386` and `amd64` variants. The easy and effective way to remove these is to note which repositories are reported as duplicates by apt-get update and remove them via the **Software Center**. Open it and choose **Edit** -> **Software Sources** -> **Other Software tab**. Simply look for the duplicate entries and uncheck them. (This is also an opportunity to remove any `source-code` repositories if you're not compiling the packages).

However, it should be noted that `apt-get update` doesn't only find duplicate entries via `sources.list`, but includes repository files located in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.  Deleting duplicate entries from there will only temporarily remove the `apt-get update` error messages if Ubuntu thinks it needs them, as the files will be automatically re-installed.  The fact that `apt-get update` will report some repositories as duplicates, and then suggest that that you run `apt-get update` itself to repair them,  is a clue that you really don't need to worry about that error message.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the duplicates were in the `prerequists-sources.list` file. I was able to continue the upgrade by running the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/prerequists-sources.list /tmp
sudo apt-get update
```

Then go to the `Update Manager` and install the updates.

Comment: Moving to /tmp is not necessary. Renaming to something which doesn't end with `.list` is enough

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (for example use `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`) and remove the duplicate line or put a `#` at the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

- Run `sudo -H nautilus` in terminal
- Find `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- Right click and open the file with a text editor (if you click on it, it will open the software sources GUI)
- Simply copy and paste into the `sources.list` and save.
- Exit terminal and you're done.

Google seems to have a problem, so I'd suggest leaving that out. I have done this on Ubuntu 12.10 (Studio version with Ubuntu desktop added and Unity for another desktop sign in).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved the Duplicate Entry problem myself by renaming `/etc/apt/sources.d` (as root) to something else and running `sudo apt-get update` to re-establish the directory and it's contents.

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/apt/sources.list` you must comment (add `#` at the start of the line) the duplicate repository entry and save changes.
After that repeat `sudo apt-get update`.

Answer (score 1):

Went through `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and removed the duplicates. After `apt-get update`, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
S="/etc/apt/sources.list" ;
S2="$S ${S}.d/*.list" ;
grep -b "^deb\`cat $S2 |
    grep -i "^deb[[:space:]]http" |
    sort |
    uniq -dc |
    sed -e 's;[[:space:]]\\+[[:digit:]]\\+[[:space:]]\\+deb\\(.\\+$\\);\\1;g'\`$" $S2
```

** Line breaks inserted for readability.*

Comment: Please explain the answer or risk having it removed.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As jokerdino as indicated, this answer would benefit substantially, if you were to edit it to add some explanation (or at least to tell the user exactly *what to do* with these lines).

Comment: This answer is wrong because it may does remove duplicate entries but it does not remove *duplicate source entries*. [see here](http://askubuntu.com/a/184446/61218) for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following to remove the duplicates

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | perl -ne '$H{$_}++ or print' > /tmp/sources.list && sudo mv /tmp/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: more info on this please

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)`

Open: `sources.list.d`

`rm google.list`

so only `google-chrome.list` remains

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate job for `uniq` which omits duplicate lines and prints only unique entries, thus we can take output of `uniq` and replace old file with `uniq`'s output:

```
 sort /etc/apt/sources.list | uniq > /tmp/sources && sudo mv /tmp/sources  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: `uniq` needs sorted input.

Comment: `sort -u` does the same job =)