# Cannot update packages in ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [W: Duplicate sources.list entry archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/w-duplicate-sources-list-entry-http-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-precise-update)

Unable to do update for Ubuntu 11.10.

This is the error message am getting on my PC:

```
root@ravi-desktop:/home/ravi# sudo apt-get update


Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
root@ravi-desktop:/home/ravi# sudo apt-get update


Fetched 72.3 kB in 1min 26s (836 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ravi-desktop:/home/ravi#
```

**Below is the error am getting:**

ravi@ravi-desktop:~$ su
Password: 
root@ravi-desktop:/home/ravi# gedit

(gedit:2424): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

** (gedit:2424): WARNING **: Could not connect to session bus
root@ravi-desktop:/home/ravi#

Comment: There is a problem with the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. How about you post that file?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. This [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/w-duplicate-sources-list-entry-http-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-precise-update) should help you to resolve. It is very similar to the error what you got.

Comment: How can i post it??

Comment: @ravi If [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/w-duplicate-sources-list-entry-http-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-precise-update) that [devav2](http://askubuntu.com/users/49542/devav2) has suggested you consult doesn't enable you to solve the problem, you can add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` to your question by editing your question (click the *edit* link). You can view the contents of that file by pressing `Alt`+`F2` and running the command `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. (You're just viewing it, not editing it yet, so you don't need to run it with `sudo`/`gksu`/`gksudo`.)