# Duplicate source error on apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates, 13.10

When I run apt-get update on my Ubuntu 13.10 Desktop install I get this error:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main       amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

What does this mean? how can I resolve it? and what issues can it create?  I want to understand the problem So if I run into it or anyone else I can help resolve it.

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry) Question. you can get a answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If means you've got the same source defined twice in your apt sources. It's a warning not an error. You could continue like this indefinitely if you wished.

To fix it, you just need to remove one of the definitions. To see all the definitions, run:

```
grep -R --include="*.list" chrome /etc/apt/
```

It's then just a case of editing (`sudoedit filename`) one of those out (either delete the line or comment it out by sticking a `#` at the beginning.

Comment: perfect solution...

Answer (score 4):

First make sure about what arquitecture are you running and just remove the entry in Software Center>Edit>Sources or remove the line in your source list.

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To find out your architecture

```
uname -a
```

Comment: best answer. because you actually know what you are doing here

Comment: This is called perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its saying that you have duplicate lines in the /etc/apt/sources.list file. you have to remove those lines which were repeated.

type this command

```
sudo awk '!a[$0]++' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

it can delete the duplicate lines.