# Duplicate sources.list entry

Tags: apt, 14.04, software-sources

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

thats all i ran, and it'd start off real smooth, then it'd get to a part where it gets stuck for like a fair ammount of time after which it'd display this error.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
    W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

of course the suggestion it suggested isnt going to work, as it's that very command after running which i came across the error. 
I've tried creating a new sources.list file, and also, in the 'other software' tab in the updater settings, i found two "canonical Partners" and thus i eradicated one of them. Still it wont work. 
there are a number of lists that the error tells of... I checked one and couldnt make any sense out of it.

Also, I installed the 32bit architecture manually so as to be able to use skype

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan have you installed the 32-bit or the 64-bit version?

Comment: @ElderGeek Im using 64bit version

Comment: @fossfreedom  i've seen that post.. even tried the stuff there. + it's for precise, though i assure you that it probably wont make a difference

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan Did you backup your original sources.list file before you made the new one?

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan My 64-bit version is ubuntu studio but doesn't have either amd64 or i386 listed in the /etc/apt/sources.list file

Comment: @ElderGeek I did backup. but the new one was like identical to the older one.

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan Question asked and answered previously. http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Comment: @ElderGeek I dont think i get you..

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan  Read http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry?

Comment: @ElderGeek Okay, sorry... Actually, none of the promising methods on that thread worked, so I tried searching for the duplicates manually again... This time, i DID manage to find a few duplicates.. to try it out, I merely changed the suspicious lines into comments and tried updating again.. it seems to work now

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan Congratulations! I'm glad it all worked out!

Comment: manually searching them is always the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You state: "Also, I installed the 32bit architecture manually so as to be able to use skype" If you need full compatibility with 32 bit code you should install the i386 version. Regardless you can solve this problem by carefully editing /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

make sure every repository appears once and only once.

or copy the original sources.list file from a live cd/dvd/usb at the same location. Or even better consult this: [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entr)
A closer look at your warnings make it clear. Look closely at this example and you'll see you have dusplicate sources for differing architectures:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Comment: I checked the file... I couldnt find any duplicate entries... plus, i even created a new one and still faced the error...

Comment: @Anas Ismail Khan Post the content of your /etc/apt/sources.list I'm sure it will be clear to someone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Elder Greek observes you have both i386 32 bit and amd_64 bit entries.
If you have synaptic or

sudo apt-get install synaptic

when you run it under Settings → Repositories → Other Software
you will find the list of all your repositories.

Delete the i386 entries and Reload (update).

If there are any more duplicates it will tell you so you can check and delete.

Comment: How do i figure out which entries are for i386?
Also, you dont neeed synaptic to get there :S 
+ last night, i checked this, and found two entries of Canonical Partners.. i removed one of them.. didnt help

Comment: Have a look at the question that this duplicates. It has much better answers, and hopefully one of those will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry