# How to fix seemingly autogenerated duplicates in sources.list in 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

So I went through the question [How to fix Duplicate sources.list entry?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry) and most of it's answer but this problem doesn't seem to get fixed. The error I am getting is:

```
Fetched 30.0 MB in 51s (577 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

The `source.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org trusty main # disabled on upgrade to trusty
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports multiverse
```

What I have tried is

- deleting the source.list file
- sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bak
- sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade
- removed one of the duplicate source repo and ensure there are no other

Command I'm using is `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`. Have even tried it without the clean.

How can I fix this problem?

---

**Background:**

1. My Emacs Tramp is giving the error `` cond: Couldn't find a proper `ls' command ``. So I tried the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15540223). But no result.
2. Tried compiling the Emacs 24.4 (not available in the software center). Couldn't because of ([`sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24`](http://www.unixbuzz.com/2014/10/install-emacs-24-4-text-editor-ubuntu-14-04/)):

   ```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libgtk-3-dev : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (= 3.10.8-0ubuntu1.2) but 3.12.2-0ubuntu4~trusty1 is to be installed
   E: Build-dependencies for emacs24 could not be satisfied.
   ```
3. Then I found [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-fix-broken-package-904637/#post4480338). Which said to fix broken packages uses the command `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, so I have to add this as an answer.

Can you show your sources.list?

I don't think the problem is with sources.list.d/*.list because the error is with ubuntu multiverse repo. I bet you have two trusty-backports multiverse entries in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` somehow. It may be a single line duplicated, or something like

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports multiverse
```

Open your `sources.list` in a text editor, find the duplicates and delete the extra lines.