# broken upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 14.10

I'm trying to upgrade to 15.04 and have hit a snag in the intermediate step going from 14.04->14.10.
After what I thought was a successful update, things are not entirely right:

1. I'm running 3.16.0-34-generic (which is 14.04)
2. `lsb_release -a` give 14.04
3. "About this computer" gives 14.10
4. Launch screen also states 14.10

When I go through Software Updater, I get an error after beginning update to 14.10 again that says, "The software on this computer is up to date. (There are no upgrades available for your system. The upgrade will now be canceled.)"

Any advice will be very appreciated!

Comment: As long as nothing's wrong, I'd say to just update. For safety's sake, you could run `sudo apt-get check`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt-get check`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I've updated the question to reflect this attempt.

Comment: I don't see any commands tried.

Comment: When I issue sudo apt-get update I get many errors of the form: W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_utopic_main_binary-amd64_Packages)

Comment: And so I tried this approach: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry and after retrying my update, the same issue occurs, where it says upgrade complete, after reboot I am still on 14.04.  And I am able to issue the commands you suggested - they all run without fault- but I am still on 14.04!

Comment: I don't think you are. I'm pretty sure it's just left-over cache. You could try selecting the advanced menu in GRUB and booting from the higher kernel version.

Comment: But from uname -r, I see I'm running 3.16.0-34-generic- which is 14.04 no?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. You're probably booting into the 14.04 kernel. I think you need 3.19.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain this kernel and boot from it?  I am not sure which direction to take here. Thanks.

Comment: hmm I don't see what this has to do with the linked post

Comment: @Zanna The duplicate flag seems to be based on [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615090/broken-upgrade-from-14-04-to-14-10#comment867131_615090)

Comment: @wjandrea that's just a warning and wouldn't cause this problem though, right?

Comment: @Zanna I would assume, yes. Maybe it's another symptom of the same problem?

Comment: @wjandrea dunno, but [this other comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615090/broken-upgrade-from-14-04-to-14-10?noredirect=1#comment867151_615090) says following that didn't help them upgrade...

Answer (score 1):

To update use :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

To check if a new version is available type:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

Run this command and the upgrade will begin:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

To force upgrade pass the -d option to sudo do-release-upgrade command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

To verify use:

```
lsb_release -a
uname -mrs
tail -f /var/log/app/log/file
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, there is also an expired bug report for it (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1452968). I think it has been invoked by not first `updating + upgrading + dist-upgrading` to the latest version of 14.04 (.3 at the time of writing).

Besides resetting the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to `trusty`, as suggested in the bug report, pinning to `utopic` sources as added by the failed `do-release-upgrade` has to be removed from the `/etc/apt/preferences` file. I succeeded to fix it as follows:

```
sudo -s
cd /etc/apt

#Remove potential pinning preferences
mv preferences preferences_old

#Restore sources
mv sources.list sources.list.old
cp sources.list.save sources.list

#Clean apt cache
apt-get clean

#Possibly repeat this block until `lsb_release -a` shows 14.04.3 and no further update/dist-upgrades possible
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade

#Finally perform the release upgrade and reboot
do-release-upgrade
```

Done. I have confirmed that this solution works on 3 different physical machines that were all affected by this problem.