# sudo apt-get update error duplicate sources.list

Tags: 14.04, updates

When I run the `sudo apt-get update` command I get the following error. How could I solve it?

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Also in Ubuntu top bar appears a stop icon that says: class 'KeyError' The cache has no package named 'wine-staging-i386'

Answer (score 0):

Regarding duplicate sources, you can fix it by using [THIS SOLUTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Wine-staging problem is caused by pipelight-multi package and it's dependencies. You can solve it by running:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Stop icon will disappear after a while.