# How to restore to default source list?

Tags: apt

Before this problem occured, i got [duplicate source.list entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-duplicate-sources-list-entry) error when do `apt-get update` command and decide to [solve](https://askubuntu.com/a/184446/253251) it.

I don't know what to do now..

[image]

**UPDATE**

Output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg [316 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release [12,9 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release       
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources [4.873 B]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages [3.311 B]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en [1.492 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                                                   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en_US                                                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy/main Translation-en                                                   
Fetched 22,9 kB in 12s (1.851 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How do i make source list isn't empty. I think is not normal having source list empty..

Comment: Saucy is Ubuntu 13.10. It is obsolete. Even if you restore source.list, you will not be able to install anything.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're sorry, but Ubuntu 13.10 is an end-of life product and is not supported any more, so it's off-topic here too.  Please refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd> via your Dash and you will see this

[image]

Activate the first checkbox and you will see this

[image]

Now, your `sources.list` is back.

The output of `sudo apt-get update` lists only the informations of your PPAs. The list-files are stored in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 use `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/` server (because 13.10 was EOL). Everytime I activate the checkbox it will generate `http://archive.ubuntu.com` server. So software properties doesnt gimme new `source.list`