# How do I revert my source.list from the source.list.backup?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, backup

After following these commands from https://askubuntu.com/a/159371/63298, it removed my `sources.list` and when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`, it's asking me to auto-remove the packages lost.

How do I revert my `source.list` from the `source.list.backup`? Now my `source.list.d` is a directory and not a list.

Answer (score 6):

With four commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
sudo apt-add-repository restricted
```

Or move or copy your backup

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list.backup /etc/apt/source.list
```

The folder `/etc/apt/source.list.d` has always been a folder, a sub-folder of `/etc/apt`. After the removal of `/etc/apt/source.list`, the folder `/etc/apt` usually contains only this folder.

Answer (score 3):

The `sources.list` can be generated in multiple ways. The GUI provided in ubuntu basically generates that file (it is in Settings -> Software). There is `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list` which is in all the proper format. You can copy the example file to original file, `cp /usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list`
And there is also online generator https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

But your file should remain in `/etc/apt` directory. You can revert changes with `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.backup /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to restore if after https://askubuntu.com/a/159371/63298 by:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list.backup /etc/apt/source.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```