# What is the reason behind apt-get's W: Duplicate sources.list entry?

Tags: apt, package-management, application-development

This question is really about the *why* of the error message. It would seem that duplicate entries in configuration file such as `sources.list` would be fairly simple to correct automatically and can be scripted fairly easily, IMHO.

According to [Anwar's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184446/295286) on the canonical question about this error message:

> If your sources.list have a line like this
>
> ```
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise universe
> ```
>
> Then it can't have another line like the below (which your files have)
>
> ```
> deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
> ```

This seems like a fairly easy thing to resolve - split line into tokens and merge the two.

And yet, `apt-get` explicitly tells the user `You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems`, even though in multiple posts on Ask Ubuntu the error actually appears when people do try to run `apt-get update`.

So is there any particular reason why `apt-get` doesn't resolve these automatically ? Is there some form of design concept/reasoning where it actually is desirable for this to be fixed manually ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get check` → check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks for broken dependencies. (`man 8 apt-get`). Seems apt-get has a lot options. You might to try this if it fixes the `sources.list` file, then it would be maybe a simple oversight in the string which gets print to stderr. Maybe in earlier times `update` fixed it and then it got moved? But I guess I'm only guessing around here.

Comment: @Videonauth  well, OK that's one way to do diagnostics, but I'm  more interested in *why apt-get doesn't do this automatically* while or before doing `apt-get update` ?

Comment: 1) What if one (or more) of the duplicates was somewhere under sources.list.d? If you needed to disable the repo, then doing it in one place wouldn't work, giving unexpected results.  2) I don't know if apt is smart enough to only check the repo once and not once per entry - which would waste resources. 3) If (more like when) I screw up my sources lists, I want to figure out what I did wrong and fix it so I don't do it again. I don't want it automatically fixed - when it might be a symptom of a larger problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And yet, `apt-get` explicitly tells the user `You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems`, even though in multiple posts on Ask Ubuntu the error actually appears when people do try to run `apt-get update`.

But that's not the only place this error is seen. It so happens that most people do tend to run `apt-get update` after making changes to the sources, which is perfectly fine, but this can also happen with other apt operations:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
[sudo] password for muru: 
$ sudo apt install vim-gnome    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim-gnome is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 328 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/jp.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/jp.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

And the problem here is the two warnings are somewhat independently generated.

`W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems` is printed when any error happens while building the apt cache. It's a catch-all generic solution: the code that prints this doesn't know (or care) which error happened, but I'd say that it's reasonable to assume for most errors that could happen when building the cache, fetching a fresh package list might well be the solution. (Think of all the apt problems we have seen because someone ran `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` without running `apt-get update`.)

But, the developers know that it's not a great suggestion. See [`apt-pkg/cachefile.cc`](https://github.com/Debian/apt/blob/4ba38b9f2611c04a0e23b84a365253e65cad2969/apt-pkg/cachefile.cc#L121):

```c
/* This sux, remove it someday */
if (_error->PendingError() == true)
   _error->Warning(_("You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems"));
```

(As always, patches should be welcome.)

> So is there any particular reason why apt-get doesn't resolve these automatically?

Because, IMHO, this is *always* the result of PEBCAK. `add-apt-repository` is smart enough not to add duplicate entries. So, this error *always* happens when someone edits the sources manually. And since humans have an infinite potential for creating interesting errors, it's not safe to have it automatically corrected.

Comment: That code comment...truly poetic, though...