# Error while upgrading ubuntu

Tags: apt, upgrade

I got this error while upgrading from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 saying that I have configured sources.list file multiple times. please help

Comment: Since install of Ubuntu 17.04 you've edited the `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and any in 'sources.list.d') and added extra lines creating the duplicates rather than checking to see if they already exist, and thus not adding them a second time. You only need to look at the files (looking for lines containing the text in the *warnings*) and remove or comment out (put a # at beginning of the line, allowing restoration if you # the wrong line) the duplicates.  Also note they likely be "W:" messages, or WARNINGS and NOT errors.  (note: "got this error" but you didn't provide the error)

Comment: "got this error = configured sources.list file multiple times" . thank you for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Check for duplicate sources with this command ([source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333252)):

```
S="/etc/apt/sources.list" ; S2="$S ${S}.d/*.list" ; grep -b "^deb`cat $S2 | grep -i "^deb[[:space:]]http" | sort | uniq -dc | sed -e 's;[[:space:]]\+[[:digit:]]\+[[:space:]]\+deb\(.\+$\);\1;g'`$" $S2
```

(You will set 2 error messages if /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory is empty. That's ok.)

If you see any red text lines on the output of this command -> then you have to edit the according file(s) and [remove the duplicate entries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry).