# Upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, 18.04, upgrade, update-manager

I want to upgrade my system, but I'm facing these problems:

1. Whenever I press on software updater nothing happens and sometimes I get an error report.
2. `sudo apt update` gives me this:

   ```
   Reading state information... Done
   1363 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:2
   ```
3. `sudo apt upgrade` gives me this:

   ```
   1116 upgraded, 195 newly installed, 0 to remove and 247 not upgraded.
   Need to get 85.1 kB/552 MB of archives.
   After this operation, 668 MB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
   Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager amd64 0.4.15-1
     400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
   Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings amd64 0.4.15-1
     400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
   Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libproxy1v5 amd64 0.4.15-1
     400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
   Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libmbim-proxy amd64 1.14.2-2.1ubuntu1
     400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
   Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libqmi-proxy amd64 1.18.0-3ubuntu1
     400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1v5_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libm/libmbim/libmbim-proxy_1.14.2-2.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

   E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libq/libqmi/libqmi-proxy_1.18.0-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb  400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

   E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
   ```

and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` give me this:

`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner`

as an edit to this question:
`cat /etc/apt/sources.list` give me this:

```
# deb http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb http://ftp.oleane.net/ubuntu/ bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse # disabled on upgrade to bionic
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse # auto generated by ubuntu-release-upgrader
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Point 2 - you have multiple duplicate entries for the same thing, remove one (or comment it out). The message tells you the file, and lines where this is created (so edit the file, or correct with gui tools).

Comment: thank you @guiverc , but can you explain how to do that? since i'm not professional.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry  (though I'd skip the entry that requires you to add a ppa & software).   I'd just comment the lines out (ie. add a "#" to the start of the line) as it's easier to undo if you make a mistake, but I also add comments to say why I made changes (inc. date)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "W: Duplicate sources.list entry"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120621/how-to-fix-w-duplicate-sources-list-entry)

Comment: @EricCarvalho OP has other problems updating system even after fixing duplicate sources. Please have a look at updated question `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix apt error "W: Target Packages ... is configured multiple times"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your sources.list might be pretty messed up. I suspect you have at least one of the ppa's mis-configured and this is preventing apt from downloading the sources from the correct locations.

I'd recommend you download the default ources.list file from [here](https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1). Next, find your sources.list file; usually this is located at `/etc/apt/sources.list`. I'd recommend you rename your current file to something like sources.list.bak and then attempt to run apt with the default sources.list as below.

```
mv sources.list sources.list.bak
cp path/to/downloaded/sources.list sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

The default sources.list will not have access to any of the software that you installed from custom ppa's but it should allow you to update was is necessary in the toolchain and then allow you to upgrade. Since you are upgrading these ppa's would need to be added again anyway. Good luck!

Comment: I opened the terminal in the folder ```/etc/apt``` and ran the command:

 ```mv sources.list sources.list.bak``` 
but i had this error:
 ```mv: cannot move 'sources.list' to 'sources.list.bak': Permission denied```

Comment: I ran these: 
```sudo mv sources.list sources.list.bak``` in ```/etc/apt``` folder and  ```sudo cp path/to/downloaded/sources.list sources.list``` 

and everything worked fine when running ```sudo apt update``` with no errors

but same errors stilled when running ```sudo apt upgrade```

but your solution was very good for solving software updater problem, it is working very well right now. Thank you so much.

Comment: software updater stopped fetching before the last 7 files and told me that Im not connected to the internet

Comment: here is the error after upgrading from software updater:

```Could not download the upgrades

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.```

Comment: ```Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb 400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb 400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1v5_0.4.15-1_amd64.deb 400  Bad URI [IP: 91.189.88.24 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is almost related to  connectivity of the server you are attempting download from. please check the connectivity with the server or change the repository link, and share the result here.

Comment: Please, consider explaining more on how to ( check the connectivity with the server or change the repository link ). try adding simple and easy to follow steps. Thank you

Comment: if you downloaded new sources.list file, go to /etc/apt and type "sudo sources.list sources.list.bak". and then type "sudo  cp path/to/downloaded/sources.list sources.list". ( if  it ask for a password, enter password for currently user you are login with). then type "sudo apt update" again.

Comment: if you get those messages again, please check the dns server connectivity. to do that go to terminal and type " ping google.com". if it dose not return the ip address of google.com, you have a problem with dns server. so please run " sudo cat /etc/resolve.conf" and share the out put of this command here.