# Upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from an ISO image installed on a USB drive

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, upgrade, usb

**Hello everyone,**

Hope you are all doing well.
Here I'm facieng some technical issues.

1. I can't upgrade my system from terminal or from software updater due to unsolved problems in question: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166164/upgrading-from-ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-ubuntu-18-04-lts).
2. And now I can't access my user account in Ubuntu and the screen showed me nothing (just a blank) after entering my password successfully, and that's happend due to some failing tryouts to install and run OpenVPN in the system.
3. I have dual boot (windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS).
4. I don't want to lose any of my data on both systems.

And the big question is: is there any possibility to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using my bootable USB flash drive without loosing any of my data or my Windows 10 or the dualboot system?

**Kindly your feedback ASAP.**

**Your cooperation is highly appreciated.**

Comment: _Abdurrahman_ Avoid losing data? Back it up, verify it; back it up again to a different destination, and verify it again. Do that before _anything_ else. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/222326/which-folders-to-include-in-backup

Comment: Backup your data. The 18.04 installer give you the option to 'Erase Ubuntu 16.045 LTS and reinstall". This will delete your Ubuntu installation and ALL data files in your Ubuntu home directory. Your Windows installation on an other partition SHOULD remain untouched. However, as K7AAY suggests, back up BOTH your Ubuntu and Windows files somewhere else. I've see questions on AskUbuntu where grub no longer allows users to access Windows, or questions where Windows was actually removed, even though the user was just reinstalling the Ubuntu OS. (You never know when something unexpected goes wrong).

Comment: A release-upgrade seem unlikely of the problems you describe on the other thread. Upgrading seems likely to make those problems worse. You must invest the time to *learn* how your system works, and how to maintain it.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for the advice.